# trying to do best way to design schema or table and find keys

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to design dynamodb schema/table and trying to find PK/SK, LSI, GSI based on use cases and query patterns.

I am new to DynamoDB and tried few table pattern but i am mixing many things.

my use case is as follows, there is a question or challenges board where users can play under one admin. there could be many such admin and users under specific admin. then each user will be tagged to multiple challenges. for e.g.

admin_id ---1-to-many--> users_id ---1-to-many-->challenges_id

challenges could be categorize as follows

- Very easy
- Easy
- Moderate
- Somewhat hard
- Hard
- Very Hard

Now user can do some action on challenges like

- solved
- pending
- InProgress
- yet_to_start
- will_start_tomorrow
- Not_Application etc.

for now i have came up with below table and json format.

{
    "TableName": "challenges",

```
 "Item": {
    "challenges_id":        { "123456" },
    "user_id":              { "123456" },
    "admin_id":             { "123456" },
    "challenges_type":      { "Very easy", "Easy", "Moderate", "Somewhat hard", "Hard", "Very Hard" },
    "challengesDesc":       { "Some desc" },

    "ActionCd":             {"solved", "Pending", "InProgress", "yet_to_start", "will_start_tomorrow", "Not_Application"},


 }
```

}

I am thinking challenges_id could be PK.
basic query patterns would be as follows.

- get all challenges tagged to each user for specific admin
- get all challenges for specific user order by action type
- get count of all challenges for each user for a specific admin

**Please let me know if need to provide more details.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the below as your schema

```
| pk      |   sk                      | status    | user    | challenges_type      | 
| admin1  |  users#user1#Very easy    | solved    | user1   |  admin1#solved       | ... some more metadata
| admin1  |  users#user1#Moderate     | InProgress|         |  admin1#InProgress   | ... some more metadata
| admin2  |  users#user3#Very easy    | solved    |         |  admin2#solved       | ... some more metadata
```

GSI1 pk:user sk:challenges_type

use cases

1. get all challenges tagged to each user for specific admin

   `Select * where pk=admin1`

   Get all the results and calculate
2. get all challenges for specific user order by action type

   `Select * from GSI1 where pk=user1`
3. get count of all challenges for each user for a specific admin

   `Select * from GSI1 where pk=user1 and sk beginswith admin1`

This will give you basic idea about how to construct dynamodb schema.